# Find Pairs For each test case print the number of distinct pairs

Tags: java, arrays

This is the question

Given an array A of N numbers, find the number of distinct pairs (i, j) such that j >=i and A[i] = A[j].

First line of the input contains number of test cases T. Each test case has two lines, first line is the number N, followed by a line consisting of N integers which are the elements of array A.

For each test case print the number of distinct pairs.

```
Constraints

1 <= T <= 10

1 <= N <= 10^6

-10^6 <= A[i] <= 10^6 for 0 <= i < N

SAMPLE INPUT 
2
4
1 2 3 4
3
1 2 1
SAMPLE OUTPUT 
4
4
```

Want a simple java code solution with explanation of all the functions and code used

Comment: Please post any code you have tried yourself so far. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: Is the sample output correct?

Comment: yes sample output is correct

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158439/find-total-number-of-i-j-pairs-in-array-such-that-ij-and-aiaj

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I threw together using a bit of code from here:

[how to take user input in Array using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622725/how-to-take-user-input-in-array-using-java)

This code asks the user to input an array by hand, you will have to implement reading in an array from some file if that is needed.

```
import java.util.*;

public class UserInput
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
            System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
            if (stdin.next().startsWith("y"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter : ");
                list.add(stdin.next());
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        stdin.close();
        System.out.println("List is " + list);
        String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i].equals(arr[j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("Pair Found! --> i: " + i + " j: " + j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```