# Find total number of substrings with 1's greater than 0's, need optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, substring

Given and string we need to find out the total number of substrings in which 1's are greater than 0's.

I approached this problem using Dynamic programming but I was not able to come up with a solution, I am successful in writing a naive-logic but I was not able to optimize the code (i.e time limit is exceeding)

Any help in optimizing or suggestions for a new approach will be help full.
The time complexity of below code is O(n^3) Any solutions to reduce the time-complexity will be helpfull.

Thank in advance.

**Code I used:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int tc =0; //total count
    string st; //original string
    getline(cin,st);
    int lent = st.size(); //size of string
    for(int i =0;i<lent;i++){ //loop to generate all possible substrings
        int j = lent-1;
        while(j>=i){
            
            string st1(st.begin()+i,st.end()-j+i); // A substring
            int c1 = count(st1.begin(),st1.end(),'1'); // count of 1's in substring
            if(c1 > st1.size()-c1) tc++; // Condition to check if 1's are more
            j--;
        }
    }
    cout << tc; // Print total substrings
}
```

**Note:** A substring is a contiguous sequence of characters within a string.
For more information about substrings visit [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring)

Comment: 1 is always greater than 0. Do you mean number of 1s is greater than number of 0s ?

Comment: This is O(n^3), the counting is O(n) too. Getting O(n^2) shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes total number of 1's in that substring should be greater than total number of 0's in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat respectively '0' and '1' as integers 1 and -1. Then the string becomes an integer array. Calculate its prefix sum array `s`, i.e., `s[0] = 0` and `s[i] = a[0] + ... + a[i - 1]`. Now every substring with number of '1's > number of '0's corresponds to a pair `(i, j)` such that `i < j` and `s[i] > s[j]`. You can then use the trick in [find total number of (i,j) pairs in array such that i<j and a[i]>a[j]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13158439/5376789). The time complexity is O(n log n).

Comment: consider string "10". then which pair (i,j) corresponds to substring "1"?

Comment: @PatrickParker Adding `s[0]=0` (and `s[i]=a[0]+...+a[i-1]`) can fix this issue.

Comment: @OpOp_1 That's a different problem.

Comment: @xskxzr Ya, Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're counting the same chars multiple times from the same start point. You can easily tally the 1's and 0's once from each start point: at the same time as you are traversing the substring. Start at length 0 substring instead of starting at the longest substring.

After this change you will have reduced from O(n^3) to O(n^2) without doing anything unusual or counterintuitive.

"is O(n^2) the most optimized solution" -- no but it's a good first step in improving your algorithm. It can be further optimized.

Comment: This approach reduces the time complexity to O(n^2) by using prefix array, is O(n^2) the most optimized solution, is it possible to attain the time complexity of O(n)?